# Generic optional function parameter return type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Given this factory

```
const index = <PK extends string, SK extends string>(pk: PK, sk: SK) => ({ pk, sk });
const i1 = index("pk1"); // type of i1 should be { pk: "pk1" }
const i2 = index("pk1", "sk1"); //  type of i2 should be { pk: "pk1", sk: "sk1" }
```

I would like to extends this so `sk` becomes optional and based on whether `sk` param is provided the return type will be `{ pk: PK }` or `{ sk: SK }`

The optional part is what makes this tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function overloading will let you do that.

You can't do this with arrow functions to the best of my knowledge - as you can't redeclare `const`, which you need for arrow functions.

You can try normal function syntax though.

```
function index<PK extends string, SK extends string>(
  pk: PK
): {
  pk: PK;
};
function index<PK extends string, SK extends string>(
  pk: PK,
  sk: SK
): {
  pk: PK;
  sk: SK;
};
function index<PK extends string, SK extends string>(pk: PK, sk?: SK) {
  return { pk, sk };
}

const i1 = index("pk1"); // type of i1 should be { pk: "pk1" }
const i2 = index("pk1", "sk1"); //  type of i2 should be { pk: "pk1", sk: "sk1" }
```